# Different Range results when running macro from different workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to select a range (R2:R and lastrow - see below!) to concatenate some value in previous cells, when I run the code in VBA mode the entire range is selected. However, when i run the code from a button in another workbook (where the macro will be stored), all of a sudden it only selects 25 rows out of 1000, very strange. any idea why?
code is below.

```
 Sub OrganizeTimeRecordingData()
    
    Dim lr As Long
    lr = Cells.Find("*", Cells(1, 1), xlFormulas, xlPart, xlByRows, xlPrevious, False).Row
    
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim wbNames As Variant, wb As Workbook, w As Workbook, El As Variant, boolFound As Boolean
    
    '1. Tracker by Month
      wbNames = Split("January,February,March,April,May,June,July,August,September,October,November,December", ",")
      For Each w In Workbooks
        For Each El In wbNames
            If w.Name = "Client Codes_" & El & "20.xlsm" Then
                Set wb = w: boolFound = True: Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If boolFound Then Exit For '
         Next
    
    '2.Concatenate Values Client name, project component description and project component task into one column at the end of the sheet of data
    
    wb.Activate
    Worksheets(1).Name = "TrackerData"
    Worksheets(1).Range("R1").Value = "Client Name - Project Component Desciption - Project Component Task"
    Worksheets(1).Range("R2:R" & lr).FormulaR1C1 = _
           "=CONCATENATE(RC[-12], "" "",RC[-5], "" "",RC[-4])"
```

Comment: There's an implicit `ActiveSheet` in `Cells.Find("*", Cells(1, 1), xlFormulas, xlPart, xlByRows, xlPrevious, False).Row`. Most likely you want to determine the `lr` *after* the logic to find `wb`, and qualify the worksheet, e.g. `wb.Worksheets(1)`.

Comment: thank you very much, always the simple solution!